# How to remove duplicies within time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two pandas dataframes, let's say:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'IN': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01'],
    'OUT': ['2023-01-10', '2023-02-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-04-10'],
    'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'GOOG', 'GOOG']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'IN': ['2023-01-05', '2023-05-01', '2023-02-05', '2023-05-01'],
    'OUT': ['2023-01-15', '2023-05-15', '2023-02-15', '2023-05-15'],
    'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'XXXX']
})
```

The question is how to remove (or copy index for later drop) from df2 such records which are already in df1 (let's say like open trades) between interval IN-OUT.

E.g. the first trade/row in df1 is AAPL from 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-10, therefore the first trade in df2 must be removed because its interval is 2023-01-05 to 2023-01-15. But the second trade/row must be kept.

Does exists a way how to do it simply without iterations?

I have tried something like:

```
df1 = df1[~((df1['Ticker'].isin(df2['Ticker'])) & (df1['IN'].between(df2['OUT'], df2['OUT'])))]
```

but did not get right result and besides, it does not work if number of rows of dataframes are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to match tickers between dataframes then use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to keep rows you want to drop:

```
idx_to_drop = (df2.reset_index().merge(df1, on='Ticker')
                  .query('(IN_y > IN_x)')['index'].tolist())
out = df2.drop(idx_to_drop)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          IN        OUT Ticker
1 2023-05-01 2023-05-15   GOOG
2 2023-02-05 2023-02-15   MSFT
3 2023-05-01 2023-05-15   XXXX
```

Intermediate step:

```
>>> df2.reset_index().merge(df1, on='Ticker')
   index       IN_x      OUT_x Ticker       IN_y      OUT_y
0      0 2023-01-05 2023-01-15   AAPL 2023-01-01 2023-01-10
1      0 2023-01-05 2023-01-15   AAPL 2023-02-01 2023-02-10
2      1 2023-05-01 2023-05-15   GOOG 2023-03-01 2023-03-10
3      1 2023-05-01 2023-05-15   GOOG 2023-04-01 2023-04-10
```

Comment: Hello @Corralien, thank you very much for your tip, it works as expected with small correction in interval condition: .query('(IN_y > IN_x) & (IN_y < OUT_x)'

Comment: Why it's not `'(IN_y < IN_x) & (IN_x < OUT_y)'`?

Comment: Suppose we want to find if 'y' is in 'x' interval.